# Post data across Wordpress sites

Tags: posts, ajax

I have two Wordpress sites. When I click on a link on Website A (the link is a country) I would like it to navigate to Website B. Website B would then display a list of results based on the link pressed on Website A e.g. the selected country.

The page I would like to navigate to on Website B uses an AJAX POST to retrieve the results though. So it's like I would like to call the AJAX JQuery function on Website B with incoming country name data from website A.

I hope that makes some sense. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use url parameters (read more here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) but of course you need to create a small function in jQuery / javascript to retrieves those.

For instance, placing a link like `https://www.websiteb.com?country=yourcountry` in your **Website A** and using a `get_url_param(country)` jQuery function in your **Website B**, you could pass the value to the AJAX call. I give you a practical example:

**Website A**

```
<a href="https://www.websiteb.com?country=yourcountry">Your Country</a>
```

**Website B**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var Country = get_url_param("country");

   //Pass your Country value to the AJAX call
   if(Country != null) init_your_ajax_call(Country);

});

function init_your_ajax_call(param){
   //etc etc
}

function get_url_param(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results==null){
           return null;
        } else {
            if(results[1].indexOf("#")){
                results = results[1].split("#");
                results = results[0];
            } else {
                results = results[1] || 0;
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

This function cleans eventual hashes `#` from the url and retrieves any parameter value you ask for. Returns `null` whether the parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess the regular expression is potentially not correct. As I'm returning null with the url (http://localhost/evidencetool?country=yourcountry). That actually, in chrome, resolves to http://localhost/evidencetool/?country=yourcountry

Comment: I ended up using 
var url_string = window.location.href; var url = new URL(url_string);
        var results = url.searchParams.get("country");

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a typo.